# How can I setup ffmpeg to continuously produce 1 second videos from piped jpgs?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ffmpeg, video

I am using ffmpeg on Ubuntu 22.04 to create 1 second mp4 videos from piped jpgs. The only issue that I have is that ffmpeg stops executing after the first set of jpgs is piped in. I need ffmpeg to continuously take in jpgs so that it can keep creating more mp4s.

This is the command line that got me closest to what I want:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i /tmp/ffmpeg_pipe -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=5" -f segment -segment_time 1 "output_%d.mp4"
```

When I piped in 10 images, `cat image_*.jpg > /tmp/ffmpeg_pipe`, I got 2 output files like expected, but ffmpeg stopped executing right after.

What can I do to be able to pipe more jpgs after the first set without having to restart ffmpeg? I want this because I have another program that is continuously creating new jpgs that I want to convert into video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to set the GOP size to 1 second by adding `-g 5` argument (5 frames applies 1 seconds at 5fps):

`ffmpeg -framerate 5 -i /tmp/ffmpeg_pipe -c:v libx264 -g 5 -f segment -segment_time 1 "output_%04d.mp4"`

---

Segment demuxer can only start a new file with a **key frame**.
Adding `-g 5` argument forces a key frame every 5 frames.

---

Testing:

Create 100 JPEG images:
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=1:d=100 image_%03d.jpg`

Write JPEG images to FFmpeg stdin pipe:
`cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -framerate 5 -f image2pipe -i pipe: -c:v libx264 -g 5 -f segment -segment_time 1 "output_%04d.mp4"`

The output is 20 MP4 video files.

---

### Update:

In case we like to write to FFmpeg multiple times, we may use the [following solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366278/217386) (see the comments).

- Create named pipe:
  `mkfifo /tmp/ffmpeg_pipe`
- Redirect named pipe to FFmpeg (Add the ampersand so that FFmpeg runs in background):
  `ffmpeg -framerate 5 -f image2pipe -i pipe: -c:v libx264 -g 5 -f segment -segment_time 1 "output_%04d.mp4" < /tmp/ffmpeg_pipe &`

Important: **Open a second terminal window**.
From the other terminal:

- Open file descriptor 3 writing (and reading) the pipe:
  `exec 3<>/tmp/ffmpeg_pipe`
- cat >&3 redirects the output to file descriptor 3:
  `cat *.jpg >&3`
  Write more images (just an example):
  `cat *.jpg >&3`
- Close file descriptor 3:
  `exec 3>&-`

Find a way to close FFmpeg process (I just pressed Ctrl-break).

Comment: The main issue remains that after I pipe the first set of jpgs, ffmpeg stops its execution. So for the next set of jpgs, I would have to restart ffmpeg. I am trying to avoid having to restart ffmpeg so that I can simply pipe in jpgs without having to worry about starting ffmpeg before each push.

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366219/prevent-automatic-eofs-to-a-named-pipe-and-send-an-eof-when-i-want-it), and updated my answer. The solution is not perfect, but it looks like it's working (note that the Linux stuff is not may expertees).

Comment: Have you noticed that I updated my answer? Not what you were looking for?

Comment: This worked great! Keeping the pipe open this way allowed for multiple inputs. Now I just need to fix my ffmpeg options to make the output videos exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To make FFmpeg read continuously from a stream or a pipe without breaking, you can use the -re option. The -re option enables infinite re-reading of the input stream. This is useful for streaming live media, or for processing media files that are being continuously updated.

For example, to stream a live RTSP stream to the internet using FFmpeg, you would use the following command:

ffmpeg -i rtsp://example.com/live.sdp -re -f flv rtmp://example.com/live

This command will read the RTSP stream continuously and stream it to the RTMP server at rtmp://example.com/live.

To process a media file that is being continuously updated, such as a video file that is being recorded in real time, you would use the following command:

ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -re -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4

This command will read the input pipe continuously and copy the video and audio streams to the output file output.mp4. The -c:v copy and -c:a copy options tell FFmpeg to copy the video and audio streams without re-encoding them.

The -re option is a very powerful tool, and it can be used to achieve a variety of tasks. However, it is important to note that the -re option can cause FFmpeg to use a lot of memory, so it is important to use it sparingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I'll keep this ffmpeg option in mind as I continue trying to figure it out though.